# Is a lightning bolt called down from Call Lightning considered 'magic' for purposes of an anti-magic zone?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, druid

Our Druid insisted that the 'magic' part of the Call Lightning spell was actually far above the targeted area, and thus the bolts called down were not considered magic for purposes of an anti-magic zone. Is there a consensus?

Answer (score 21):

### Call Lightning doesn't function within an Antimagic Field.

Your Druid is partially right.  The spell Call Lightning is, in fact, centered on a point 100 feet above the caster, and so the spell itself isn't ended when the Druid enters an antimagic field.  Unless the antimagic field is centered 100 feet above the ground, the *call lightning* spell isn't going to be suppressed by it. However, the spell *antimagic field* states:

> Spells and other magical effects... are suppressed in the sphere
>   and can't protrude into it.

While there isn't a clear and specific definition for what counts as a "magical effect", an attack generated by a spell certainly is. In addition, even if the Druid's interpretation was correct, he still wouldn't be able to target creatures withing the antimagic field.  The area of *call lightning* is:

> in the shape of a cylinder that is 10 feet tall with a 60-foot radius

Now, while most of the spell's area is still active when an antimagic field covers part of it, the part that intersects with the antimagic field is no longer effected by the *call lightning* spell, and isn't within the spell's range anymore.  To target a *call lightning* bolt, you:

> choose a point you can see within range.

Since the antimagic section is no longer in the cylinder defined by the spell's range, it can't be targeted by a bolt.

In general, unless the spell specifically states otherwise, all parts of a spell description are part of the spell's magical effects, and are suppressed in an antimagic field.

Comment: You're right, and I upvoted, but the range of Call Lightning is 120 feet.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57226/discussion-on-answer-by-ducktapeal-is-a-lightning-bolt-called-down-from-call-lig).